# Input field should not submit if empty after button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, input

I have a search field and user can only input 2 or more characters:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\models\User;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\widgets\Select2;
use yii\helpers\Url;
$session = Yii::$app->session;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\PayslipTemplateSearch */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="searchbox" style="padding: 0; margin-right: 0px;">  

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['searchresults'],
        'method' => 'get',
        'id' => 'searchForm'
    ]); ?>

    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" pattern=".{2,}" title="Keyword should have a minimum of 2 characters" required>
       <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">&#x1f50d;</button>
       </span>
    </div>
    <span class="error">Enter at least two characters</span>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>

<style type="text/css">
.error {
  display: none;
  font: italic medium sans-serif;
  color: red;
}
input[pattern]:invalid ~ .error {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    $(".btn-primary").click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#searchForm').submit();
    });
    $('.dropdown-responsive').addClass('manageadmindd');
    $('.select2-bootstrap-append').addClass('ddcontainer');
})

// function showError(txt)
// {
//   var err = document.getElementById('error');
//   err.innerHTML = txt;
//   err.style.display = 'block';
// }
</script>
```

Now, if I hit the ENTER KEY, it will display this:
[image]

But, if I press that search button, it will redirect to the search results page with a PHP error because it doesn't receive any keyword.

So how do I prevent this from happening?

EDIT:

I put all my HTML code above. I am using Yii2 php framework.

Comment: Can u provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: please include relevant code.such as click event of the button

Comment: I don't have any click event for this one. the `pattern` attribute does the error message, I think.

Comment: Please give relevant code.. Above code doesnt create the desired output

Comment: but that's the relevant code. okay, I will edit and put all my html code in my question.

Comment: done editing my code. That's all I have.

Comment: `$('#searchForm').submit();` Remove this code from your script

Comment: I tried removing it but it doesn't submit anymore.

Comment: provide `type="submit"` attr to search button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're preventing the button's default behavior, and then manually calling the form's `submit`.

Change your button to an `input[type=submit]` field, and remove the code that you add an event listener to it, and everything should work as you expected:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="&#x1f50d;">
```

And remove:

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#searchForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('#searchForm').submit();`
Remove this code from your script.
Its triggering form submit. Even tough you have validated input field with pattern, the script will trigger the form submit action.

Also provide `type='submit'` Attribute to your search button.

Answer (score 1):

Add the disabled attribute on your button, then use your own javascript function to test if the field has input. If it does, remove the disabled attribute from the submit button.

```
$( '.my-input' ).on( 'keyup', function( e ) {
    var inputVal = $( this ).val();
    if( !!inputVal ) {
        $( '.my-submit' ).removeAttr( 'disabled ');
    } else {
        $( '.my-submit' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );

    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/ZbXYOx